# Does Importing CSV has an Issue with the browser?

Tags: php, cakephp, browser, csv, import

I am developing an app (with cakephp) that allows to import a csv file. i am running a machine with windows 7 seven OS. The import CSV looks good to me but on my client says that its not working properly... here is the browser that he uses

Windows:

IE 6.0
Safari 4

Mac

Safari 6
Firefox 9

my question now is, does browsers really matters?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you handle the display yourself of the CSV or you simply dump the raw data to the browser?

Comment: Do you display the data through for example an html / javascript table or you output the data contained in the file without formatting it at all?

Comment: The data i well formatted... i have a data validator script

Comment: By formatting I didn't mean "has commas and new lines at the right places", I meant visually formatting, through html for example... why don't you show us some code, it will make things clearer

Comment: do you send headers while downloading the csv file, headers plays very important role

Comment: @PankajKhairnar i am importing a csv file, not downloading

Answer (score 0):

No Browser doesn't matter, Its just a normal file upload, best way is to get the exact csv your client is using and try to upload and print the data of file, Problem seems to be in csv file or in the code but definitely not in browser.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is also about the file. I don't have a problem when the csv was from a windows machine but if the csv was came from a Mac machine the import doesn't work.

Comment: also check delimiter in the file, it may be different than your delimiter.

Comment: i am using this `fgetcsv($handle, 0, ",")` to check the delimiter

Comment: Some people also use tab for separating values, check it in actual csv

Comment: its called tsv that's tab separated values, tabs are used instead of comma